# How do I convert a string like "\\u0012" into a Char "\u0012"

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, char

The string is literary "\\u0012" (example). I have to make it into a "\u0012" (notice the \ and \\). Char.Parse() doesn't work.

There must be a simple way. Perhaps try to convert the 0012 into a byte array and then somehow convert that into a char...

Comment: Are you trying to get a _string_ or a `Char`? Where are you seeing this string - during debug?

Comment: It doesnt really matter. Just to convert a string into a unicode char.

This is from a raw formatted javascript I get from web scraping.

Comment: It does matter if you want us to understand exactly what the issue is.

Comment: @Edza: Where is this string coming from? If it's part of something like a JSON response, I'd suggest just using a JSON parser...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are using visual studio and you are checking the value of the variable and it contains a ""\\"" then the string really only contains a single blackslash.  If you see it contains ""\\\\" then it would contain a "\\" the escape character in C# is a single "\" and is not actually contained in the **String** object's value.  A beter example with what you have attempted would be appreciated.

Comment: @Oded ehmm.... I think I just somehow misstate the question, it's really irrelevant whether I convert it into a string with a single char or a single char.

Comment: @Edza - Let us determine what does and does not matter when attempting to help you.  Telling us something that does matter, does not matter, is a great way to alienate the very people that want to provide you an answer.  Until you provide clarification to our questions I have to downvote this question.

Comment: @Ramhound NO, I am NOT checking vs debug. It's the string that is LITERARY "\\u0012" (example). In debug it would be "\u0012" btw.

Comment: @Edza - If you feel your question is not clear, edit the question, so it is clear.  Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: @Edza - My experience tells me otherwise.  When I generate a path to a file, the string value, always appears to contain two "\\" and not a single "\" like it actually does.  When you say **LITERARY** do you actually mean **LITERALLY** by chance?

Comment: @Jon - not a JSON response. It is some javascript from web scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx).

```
string unescaped = Regex.Unescape(mystring);
```

Comment: YAY WORKS! Thank you. :)

That was very fast. SO is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking to replace the "\" with "\"? Or are you trying to create a char(12)?

I think what you are trying to do is

```
string originalString = Regex.Unescape("\\u0012");
char newChar = Char.Parse(originalString);
```

As mentioned above, this works. Tested.
Just make sure to add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: @Oded - The original answer compiled without issues.

Comment: @Ramhound - No it doesn't. The first version in the edit history is not the very original (there is a 5 minute edit grace period).

Comment: He's right, it worked in my test code because I wrote it differently, but I changed it slightly when I posted it here and caused an escape syntax error. But unescape is much more elegant. If you don't want to use the Regex library though, you can use string replace with the original edit.